# How to count in a collection, with multiple documents that have the same value in their attributes Flutter/Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection Tools that has multiple documents with shared attributes and one of them being toolName, I would like to count the tools that have the same name and return their value. Meaning if 2 documents have "toolName = Screen Reader" then the count would be 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEmYZ.png

This is what I tried so far, however it is returning 4 as length but there's only 2 "Screen Readers" in the documents
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa7nB.png

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count all the tool names like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Tools').get().then((value) {
  var toolNamesCounted = Map();
  List toolNames = [];

  value.docs.forEach((data) {
    var doc = data.data();

    toolNames.add(doc['toolName']);
  });

  toolNames.forEach((e) {
    if (!toolNamesCounted.containsKey(e)) {
      toolNamesCounted[e] = 1;
    } else {
      toolNamesCounted[e] += 1;
    }
  });

  print(toolNamesCounted);
  // result should be:
  //  {Screen Reader: 2, ...etc }
});
```